How to stop constant network activity by "system updates" system app?
The app/process "system updates" started using network data constantly a few days ago, also I think the battery is drained faster.
Should I be worried about being hacked, or is this just some bug?
And how do I make this stop?
I'm using crDroid 9.0 (android 13) ROM (from here, I think) on Samsung S8.
The first screenshot from android settings shows data usage in about 3 days. And the second screenshot from PCAPdroid app shows data usage in a few minutes, to see the IP adresses it connects to. Seems the IPs belong to google. Also, I think my phone is identified as pixel phone by google, maybe this has something to do with this, maybe google tries to update this "pixel phone".. But what seems weird is the data speed, which is always only a few KB/s, if google only tried to download pixel update files, I would think it could reach higher speeds.



"System Updates", by itself, is probably a system app, you can use ADB tools to delete it

But is it safe to do it? I guess this app doesn't do anything useful on a custom rom anyway, but won't it crash some other things on android, maybe I can first just kill this process somehow to see if anything happens

Yes, but that is just my guess, you could also try looking for the system app and revoking its network permissions.

That would be excellent (if the app won't use much battery afterwards), but how can I do that - I can't find this system app in settings > programs, with "show system apps" checked.

U could try searching for a "disable system updates" option in the settings

Can't find anything like that in the settings

I guess it would be easier if I could figure out the app/process name (like com.google.android.xxxxx), but I don't know how to do that, as I said - I can't find this app in list of apps on my phone, though it has a separate entry in mobile data usage section.

well, I'm out of ideas, GL
